Construction of sparse matrix for Poisson Equation with Neumann BC
I am solving Poisson's equation in 2D numerically, imposing Neumann Boundary Conditions. I am using the sparse factorization of the problem $L_h u_h = f$. I am having trouble when extending the matrix $L_h$, since I am not sure I am imposing the right coefficients. Right now, for N=10, this is my sparse matrix: $L_h$ sparse matrix with values. Where I am using the tridiagonal block form, and extending it with $-2*I$ in the upper right block and lower left block, since these are the blocks that multiply the boundaries, and therefore the FDM approximation has coefficients 2.
I wanted to know if this is correct, because I am failing to obtain the expected result, and maybe this is the problem or maybe it is the Right Hand side, which would be rare.
